# Bandwidth limitations of network loopback device?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, loopback, interface

I have several JVMs that all listen to TCP 80 each bound on their own 127.0.100.1 -> 127.0.100.255 range.

Is there a theoretical limit to the effective bandwidth that can be pushed through the LO device?  Is this simply a limitation of the kernel and TCP stack vs. the limitations of a 'regular' network interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, there's no NIC-speed issues, just your CPU/s, kernel and stack.